# How to clear opaque affixed divs height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap and a bunch of custom CSS for social media icons (located [here](http://codepen.io/h3xc0ntr0l/pen/GpmyGQ)), I created a pen to demo (and test) my code. The goal was to create icons that would automatically fit there parent div (horizontal or vertical, etc), and I have everything working except for one small problem. I have both of the divs affixed (one horizontal, one vertical), and 100% opaque before the affix is triggered. However, and I know *why*, the view is still being rendered with what basically looks like a giant margin between the top of the document and the page title. How can I clear this, while still using `display:inline-block`?

Here is the CSS for the related divs & classes, but I'd recommend checking out the [pen](http://codepen.io/h3xc0ntr0l/pen/MamOwE) first because visually seeing it expalins the issue much better.:

```
.snav {
  top:50%;
  margin-left:-15px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width:5rem;
  height:25rem;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:99;
  transition: 1s all ease-in;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  opacity:0;
}


.horiz{
  top:0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  z-index:99;
  left:50%;
  transition: 1s all ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  opacity:0;
  display:inline-block;
}

#horiz{
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
  width:26.6rem;
  height:5rem;  
}

.affix{
  opacity:.5;
}

.affix:hover{
  opacity:.9;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to expand "and I know why" statement - it is now not possible to rate answers since they may just repeat what you *know*.

Answer (score 0):

The gap between the top of the page and the title is because the social icons widget is still within content flow.

Try adding `position: fixed;` to the `.snav` style rule to take it out of content flow and the title will go to the expected position.